# jQuery change button image not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Just learning jQuery and am using it to change the background image on a button triggered by a mouseover event. All of the console output fires at the correct times, but my image never changes. No errors are thrown. What am I doing wrong?

In the `<head>` element, I have this preloading script:

```
    function preloader() {
        if (document.images) {
            console.log("preloading images");
            contact_green = new Image();
            contact_green.src = "http://www.xxxx.com/images/contact_green.png";
        }
    }

    function addLoadEvent(func) {
        var oldonload = window.onload;

        if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
            window.onload = func;
        } else {
            window.onload = function() {
                if (oldonload) {
                    oldonload();
                }
                func();
            }
        }
    }

    addLoadEvent(preloader);
```

That seems to work fine, in the sense that I get the output "preloading images". Not sure that it has the correct scope, however.

Then, in the `<body>` element, I have this button defined:

```
    <td>
        <button id='contact' class='CXIII' onclick="btnContact()">
            <img id="logo" src="images/contact_blue.png">
        </button>
    </td>
```

Finally, I have a script that is supposed to change the image on this button upon a mouseover event:

```
<script>

    function showHover(img) {
        console.log("show hover");
        if (img) img.src = contact_green;;
    }

    $("#contact").hover(
        function () {
            console.log("mouse in");
            showHover(this);
        },
        function () {
            console.log("mouse out");
        }
    );
</script>
```

I get the console output, but the image doesn't change. There are no errors thrown, either.

Comment: Why are you not just using addEventListener?

Comment: Because I am trying to learn jQuery.

Comment: If you are using jQuery, might as well write `$("#contact").click(btnContact);`

Comment: It's not a click event. It's a mouse hover.

Comment: I am talking about the inline event handler `onclick="..."`, which is a *click* event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting an object, not the source of the image

```
img.src = contact_green;;
```

needs to be

```
img.src = contact_green.src;
```

And you are not setting the image, but the button.

```
showHover(this);
```

needs to be

```
showHover($(this).find("img")[0]);
```

and since you are using jQuery

```
$(window).load(preloader);
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Where do I put that last line?

Comment: Where ever you have `addLoadEvent(preloader);`

Comment: OK. I added that line immediately after `addLoadEvent(preloader)`. Now I see `preloading images` appear twice in the console output, but still no image change.

Comment: You were supposed to REMOVE the other line.

Comment: Is that last script in the body or the head?

Comment: Ah, updated the code, `showHover($(this).find("img")[0]);` You should have gotten an error message in the console. Learn to use the debugger. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

Comment: That was it. Thanks. I was using the console and did not get any error messages at all. Now I need to study this code to understand it better. Thanks again!

Comment: Ah you are right no error should have been fired since it would just set a property on the object. There would have been an error if it was a method. I think I need to go to bed. lol